# Android MYSQL Select * to Consctruct Java Object

Tags: java, php, mysql

I am trying to retrieve data from a MYSQL database in android using the following code:

```
...
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity()
                                .getContent()));
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
                String line = "";
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                    break;
                }
                in.close();
                responseString = sb.toString();
                responseString = responseString.substring(0,
                        responseString.length() - 1);
                showMessage(responseString);
                System.out.println(responseString);
                // Handle Response
                user.orderList.clear();
                String[] tmp1 = responseString.split("\\|");
                for (String s : tmp1) {
                    String[] tmp2 = s.split(",");
                    Order tmp3 = new Order();
                    tmp3.orderId = tmp2[0];
                    tmp3.placerName = tmp2[1];
                    tmp3.itemName = tmp2[2];
                    tmp3.payment = tmp2[3];
                    tmp3.locationString = tmp2[4];
                    user.orderList.add(tmp3);
                    System.out.println(tmp3.toString());
                }
...
```

This gets the response from the php file as a String and splits the response based on , and | 
Here is the PHP code the returns its data back to the Java Code:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE (location_lat BETWEEN '".$_POST['LatMin']."' AND '".$_POST['LatMax']."') AND (location_long BETWEEN '".$_POST['LongMin']."' AND '".$_POST['LongMax']."')");
        if($sql){
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {

echo ($row['order_id'] . "," . $row['placer_name'] . "," . $row['item_name'] . "," . $row['payment_amount'] . "," . $row['location_string'] . "|");
            }
        } else{
            echo 'Failed. SQL Error occured.';
        }
```

The issue is that for some reason I am only getting 4 of the values: placerName, itemName, payment, locationString. However the orderId does not return anything.

Database:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried you generated query in phpmyadmin and check order id coming in it?

Comment: Same result. It still returns only 4

Comment: post your table sql dump here.